# Stop music of from Other APP

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

If in background the default music player is running and if I use my app to play music, both runs simultaneously.

Is there a way to stop background music player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement Mediaplayer's `AudioFocus`. To do this you need to get an instance of the `AudioManager`. Once you have the instance you can then use `requestAudioFocus`.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    
// Request audio focus for playback
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
// Use the music stream.
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
// Request permanent focus.
AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);   

if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("AudioFocus", "Audio focus received");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.d("AudioFocus", "Audio focus NOT received");
        return false;
    }
}
```

`AudioFocus` is assigned to each application that requests it. When your app receives focus it can pass an `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` which provides callbacks for when an focus change happens.

If app gains audio focus, and another app requests audio focus, the focus will be given to the other app. Android will notify your app via an `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` so that your app can respond to the change. To receive focus events, you need to pass an instance of `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` like this.

```
private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
          new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                  public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                             AudioManager am =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    switch (focusChange) {

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                           // Lower the volume while ducking.
                           mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                           break;
                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                           pause();
                           break;

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                           stop();
                           ComponentName component =new ComponentName(AudioPlayerActivity.this,MediaControlReceiver.class);
                           am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(component);
                           break;

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                           // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                           mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                           mediaPlayer.start();
                           break;
                           default: break;
}
}
};
```

Reference Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html

Comment: thanks Abhi , Now I am able to stop music but unable to resume.

Comment: The other app must request for the audio focus. It will be granted to that application.

Comment: I did'nt get you what you want to say?

Comment: Understand it this way. Your app has implemented AudioFocus. So when your app starts, audio focus is granted and all the other sounds stop. Similarly if any other app with `AudioFocus implemented` when started, will play its sound and all other sounds will stop. So the other app must request for the audio focus.

Comment: that means if other app not implemented AudioFocus then it should not resume.

Comment: If AudioFocus is not implemented then media would play but it would play simultaneously with the other one I think.

Comment: I am using 'abandonAudioFocus' after sound play completed but it would also not resume.

Comment: Please post your source code.

Comment: For playing Sound                                                                                                            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.raw.unlock);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    am.abandonAudioFocus(focusChangeListener);
                }
            });  and used your code.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there in the code. What exactly are you trying achieve? The next media will start only when you initiate the other app.

Comment: AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN change to AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT. it should work after call am.abandonAudioFocus(focusChangeListener) it to sound complete. thanks

Comment: The information in this answer is very helpful, thank you.